# Garbage Announce Response from UDP tracker (c - torrent client)

Tags: c, sockets, udp, torrent

I'm writing a torrent client in C which implements the UDP tracker protocol as described here:

http://www.libtorrent.org/udp_tracker_protocol.html

My project is located here : https://github.com/unovongalixor/uvgTorrent

I am successfully sending the connect request and receiving my connection ID.

I use the following code to prepare all of my data in a packed struct which is then sent to the tracker via a udp. Interestingly enough if I break the connection ID by wrapping it htonll() i get an error as described by the protocol. i.e. action == 3 and the error message indicated "Connection ID mismatch."

However when I send the connection ID as I received it I get a garbage response. action == 16777216. the transaction ID matched the one I provided but none of the other expected information is there.

Anyone have any similar experiences? Here's my code.

```
this->generate_transID(this);

/* set up the packet to send to server */
int32_t transID = *this->last_transaction_id;

struct tracker_announce_request conn_request;
conn_request.connection_id = *this->connection_id;
conn_request.action = htonl(1);
conn_request.transaction_id = transID;

/* extract info hash */
Linkedlist * info_hash_list = string_utils.split(torrent->hash, ':');
const char * info_hash = (char *) info_hash_list->get(info_hash_list, 2);
// convert 50 character info_hash stringlocated in magnet_uri to 20 byte array
string_utils.hex_to_int8_t(info_hash, conn_request.info_hash, 40); // need to verify that tracker is receiving the correct value here

// generate peer id
for(int i = 0; i<=19; i++){
    conn_request.peer_id[i] = rand_utils.nrand8_t(rand() % 10);
}

conn_request.downloaded = htonll((uint64_t)0);
conn_request.left = htonll((uint64_t)0);
conn_request.uploaded = htonll((uint64_t)0);
conn_request.event = 0;
conn_request.ip = htonl(0);
conn_request.key = htonl(rand_utils.nrand32(rand() % 10));
conn_request.num_want = htonl(-1);
conn_request.port = htonl(5050);
conn_request.extensions = htonl(0);
// send packet
this->tracker_socket->send(this->tracker_socket, &conn_request, sizeof(struct tracker_announce_request));
```

Comment: `16777216` = `0x1000000`. Does that ring a bell? Don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Assemble the *bytes* you need to send, and send them. Don't rely on the compiler to do that for you. It may or it may not, subject to half a dozen or more dependencies.

Comment: I'll change the way i'm sending the data, but no, 0x1000000 doesn't ring a bell to me. Care to clue me in?

Comment: i've gone ahead and used memcopy to move the values into an array, and I get the same behavior. the packet size and offsets matches this document: http://xbtt.sourceforge.net/udp_tracker_protocol.html